# autojump jump based on parent directory

Tags: bash, autojump

Is there any way to jump to a location based on the parent directory? Most of the times the code base will have the same child directory name such as `src`. In the following case, is there a way to jump to `/tmp/temp1/test1`?

```
$ j -s
10.0:   /tmp/temp1/test1
14.1:   /tmp/temp2/test1
28.3:   /tmp
________________________________________

52:  total key weight
3:   stored directories
28.28:   current directory weight
db file: /home/<user>/.local/share/autojump/autojump.txt

$ j temp1
autojump: directory 'temp1' not found
Try `autojump --help` for more information.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably ask that in the same place where you got the `autojump` - https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues . The `bash` itself has only the `CDPATH`. P.S. Oh wait, you have already asked: https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/424

Comment: @Dummy00001 I will update the post if / when I get any response from the maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible with multiple arguments as described in the man section.

Courtesy: wting

https://github.com/wting/autojump/issues/424#issuecomment-226813555